# Using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to display all the `threeDay.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday.high.fahrenheit` 's, because `forecastday` is a array. How would I use `ng-repeat` in this situation? Here is my code to just display the value of fahrenheit for the first piece of data in the forecastday array.

```
<body ng-app="ForecastApp">
  <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
    <p>{{ threeDay.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat like so in your case:

```
<body ng-app="ForecastApp">
    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">

        <p ng-repeat="forecastday in threeDay.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday">
            {{ forecastday.high.fahrenheit }}
        </p>

    </div>
</body>
```

Just loop through all your threeDay.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday table and show every high.fahrenheit element of it.

Comment: This is great, but what if I wanted to also do other data in the forecastday array?

Comment: I'm quite new to this forum, I didn't know there was so much rude concurrence on here. As Shyju mentioned, you can access any other element of the "forecastday" array just like you did with "forecastday.high.fahrentheit".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `threeDay.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastda` is a collection/array and each item in that array has a `high` property which again has a `fahrenheit` property

```
<body ng-app="ForecastApp">    
  <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">

     <p ng-repeat="f in threeDay.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday">
        {{f.high.fahrenheit}}
    </p>    

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this is great, but what if I wanted to also display other data in that array?

Comment: Just access another property the same way we accessed `fahrenheit`. Change `fahrenheit` to the other property name.